# How to find a single checkbox's checked state in a WebGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, model-view-controller

Here is my WebGrid with a checkbox column with the id = chkbox1:

```
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "grid", .class = "table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed", .name = "grid1"},
                            emptyRowCellValue:="No Records Found",
                            headerStyle:="grid-header",
                            columns:=grid.Columns(
                            grid.Column(header:="Select", format:=Function() Html.CheckBox("chkboxname", htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "chkbox1", .value = "Item"})),
                            grid.Column("item_id", "Item ID"),
                            grid.Column("item_desc", "Description")))
```

Here are my functions for turning the WebGrid into a json object:

```
<script>
                document.getElementById("btnGetRows").addEventListener("click", getTableData);

                function getTableData() {
                    //debugger;
                    var _griddata = gridTojson();
                    var url = '@Url.Action("GetGridViewRows")';
                    alert(_griddata);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { griddata: _griddata }
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        if (data != "") {
                            $('#grid').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }

                function gridTojson() {
                    var json = '{';
                    var otArr = [];

                    var tbl2 = $('#grid tbody tr').each(function (i) {
                        var chkbox2 = $("#chkbox1").is(":checked");
                        //var chkbox = document.getElementById("chkbox1"); //tried this too
                        if ($(this)[0].rowIndex != 0) {
                            if (chkbox2) {
                                x = $(this).children();
                                var itArr = [];
                                x.each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).children('input').length > 0) {
                                        itArr.push('"' + $(this).children('input').val() + '"');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
                                    }
                                });
                                otArr.push('"Row' + i + '": [' + itArr.join(',') + ']');
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    json += otArr.join(",") + '}'
                    return json;
                }
            </script>
```

What I'm wanting to do is loop through and get any rows that have the checkbox checked and store the row data in the json object. If I check all the checkboxes on the WebGrid, the "if" statement becomes true. Even though the checkboxes have the same ID, shouldn't it still work since the var chkbox2 = $("#chkbox1").is(":checked") is in the loop and it resets it every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to do this:

```
                           if ($(this).find("td").children().is(":checked")) {
                                x.each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).children('input').length > 0) {
                                        itArr.push('"' + $(this).children('input').val() + '"');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

instead of this:

```
                    var chkbox2 = $("#chkbox1").is(":checked");
                    if ($(this)[0].rowIndex != 0) {
                        if (chkbox2) {
                            x = $(this).children();
                            var itArr = [];
                            x.each(function () {
                                if ($(this).children('input').length > 0) {
                                    itArr.push('"' + $(this).children('input').val() + '"');
                                }
                                else {
                                    itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
                                }
                            });
                            otArr.push('"Row' + i + '": [' + itArr.join(',') + ']');
                        }
                    }
```